# How to integrate git bash in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-bash

How to integrate git bash in visual studio code? I typed " open user setting " then I am getting this window:

[image: Visual Studio Screenshot]

Comment: vscode already has source control plugin installed. pull some code and make some changes and you will the diff in the source control area.. also you can use plugin like git-lens to see the committer

Answer (score 0):

VSCode has [support for git](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_git-support) built in.

You might need to check that the directory containing the `git` executable is on your `PATH` [environment variable](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them).  Alternatively, in [`settings.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings), set `git.path`, for example:

```
{
  "git.path": "d:/opt/git-for-windows-2.23.0/bin/git.exe"
}
```

You also need to install [`git`](https://gitforwindows.org/) first.

Answer (score 0):

Following steps have to be followed to integrate Git Bash with Visual Studio Code:

#### Step-1

You have to open settings by File->Preferences->Settings or by pressing Ctrl+,  AND click on the Open Settings(JSON) icon on the top right corner of vs code editor

#### Step-2

On clicking, you will see the settings page. You have to copy:

```
            "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"
```

and paste at the last of all settings. Make sure that you have installed git bash on your computer.

#### Step-3

And that’s all when you will reopen VS Code then you will see that Git Bash has been integrated. Now you can run Git Bash commands directly in VS Code.

Comment: In Step-2, I cannot tell what "paste at the last of all settings" means.